# When processes are ill-defined is it ok to just "do what worked last time"?

Tags: communication

Another department needs certain information each month.  I literally don't know what they actually want or if I even know the right answer.

I guessed (telling them it was a guess) and they said that couldn't be right. So I guessed again and never heard back from them.

The next month I used the same formula for guessing and nobody complained.

I honestly think that the information I'm feeding them in wrong, or at least not 100% correct.

Should I just keep giving them the same answer every month?   I'm afraid that if I raise this issue I'll open up a big can of worms.

Comment: Added an answer that can help you. Just as a comment, do you say that this "worked last time" because they didn't complained? Perhaps it didn't work and they also didn't complained... just, careful with interpreting silence with everything OK

Comment: This would have a critical and red flag "impacts" depending on your the type of information. For ex: Healthcare and financials. I would highly recommend you look into the data you are required to report and analyze the impact. Start from there. You would most likely find your answer whether its important to be 100% correct or just "wing it"

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable in general - it would depend on what exactly the information is, how important it is, how easy it would be to "test" the correctness of the information and whether that would be a necessary part of "using" the information, who might know the correct answer, what your relationship with them is, why they're asking you for the information, whether knowing is supposed to be part of your job and, if so, why you don't know the information, etc. When in doubt, ask your manager.

Comment: vtc - this is just opinion. also - deary me. i'm not sure what your job is but it sounds like you should not be doing it.

Answer (score 6):

> I literally don't know what they actually want or if I even know the right answer.

If that is so, then *asking them to clarify* on what they want is what you should try first.

After that, if you still don't quite get it I suggest you *contact someone that does*.

You could also *ask your boss* on the correct way of proceeding with this information, so he/she can explain the process to you so you can make it right next time.

Whatever you do, **don't keep giving them information you made up**, as this could backfire on you eventually. Sometimes it's better to be humble and say *"I don't know, would you mind showing me?"* than faking it.

Comment: I think can even get fired for it

Comment: Followup: I asked them to sit down with me for this month's iteration. I did what I usually did, and they saw that their request didn't make sense in my context. She gave me a way to do a workaround this month and promised to fix it for next month.  Conclusion: more communication is always the best solution!

Comment: @TomOnTime glad you worked this out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do a little research to see if there is a well documented methology for reporting the information you are asked for in your industry. I going to assume that what you are asked to report on is not well defined by some standard such as the U.S. Generally Accepted Accounting Principles (GAAP). In that case you have to figure out what your stakeholders need. Then determine what data to collect, anylize and report. When designing a reporting methodology it is important that the data is:

1. Useful
2. Well Understood,
3. Reproducible
4. Compared (over time periods and accorss other dimentions)

## Useful

Have key users of your data explain to you what decisions they will make using your data. This is much better than asking them what data they want because the often don’t know what they want, or what is available but they do know what decisions they have to make. Then talk to them about how the data available and the analysis you can perform can help them make decisions with confidence. Be aware that many times, directional changes are more important to people than very actuate numbers. For example, is the rate of sales in a region increasing? Accuracy is often expense, if even possible, figure out what is good enough for people make confident decisions.

## Understood

Document you methodology for collecting the data. Provide a very short summary of how the data was collected and analyzed. If you methodology can’t be explained in a very short summary then use different methodology. You may be tempted to say that explanation must be complex because the domain is complex however in that case the result will be useless because different people will understand your methodology differently. Call out any assumptions you make, e.g. are you assuming fixed interest rates or the size of assigned work items doesn’t vary widely. A few examples with round numbers often helps. Have key users of you data explain back to you in their words what data means to them so that you verify you have explained it well. Be prepared to provide you raw data and calculations for complete transpanrency.

## Reproducible

Make sure you follow the same methodology every week. That’s one reason documenting the methodology is so important. Automate the collection and analysts of the data. The could be as simple as setting up an Excel fille with formulas you use every week. Avoid manual steps. Where they are unavoidable then create tests. This could be calculating results two different ways to verify the results or computing statistics which are sensitive, e.g. if unit cost for a category of items sold is with in a narrow band, you should check your work it it changes a lot in one week.

## Comparable

Part of this is being reproducible.  Another part is being aware of the variability in your data. Be aware of the causes of variation in you data, e.g. if you sell a product to business, reporting revenue per business day may be more meaning than total revenue for the month. Report on explained variations, e.g. a supplier had a unexpected shutdown in their factory. Don’t just report averages, report variance, e.g. show how this weeks number lies withing the range of normal values over the last number of weeks.

---

My final advice that it is better to open the can of worms now than when a bad decsion has been made using misunderstood data and fingers start pointing. If people are unwilling to talk to you about his, then be open about providing your own answers to the open questions and make is easy for people to approve or disapprove of your solutions.